# How to use Ember action helper in element append to the DOM

Tags: ember.js, action, helper

First, I wanna let you know that I'm just starting at Ember, so, if is there a better way to accomplish the same result, feel free to point at that.

I have a component called "select-room", it should work as the fields "Quartos", "Adultos" and "Crianças" at [this](https://novosite.cvc.com.br/hoteis) site.

In this site when the field "Quartos" is changed, will be added or removed more selects fields on the form, the same happen when the value of "Crianças" change. I was able to accomplish this behavor using DOM manipulation, but when appending a select field like this html+= ''; the action helper don't work.

Link to the full code is at this repo in Github: https://github.com/darwinboaventura/embercvc

What is the best to way to solve this problem?

Comment: Repository contains no code, except default files.

Comment: @kumkanillam I just checked the repository, all the files are in the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use data set on the component to render DOM elements using handlebars syntax.

```
{{#if items}}
  <select onchange={{action ..}}>
    {{#each items as |item|}}
      <option value={{item.value}}>{{item.label}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
{{/if}}
```

See this example: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/

Overall, you should go through the tutorial, so you have a better grasp of how things work in Ember. Start here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/tutorial/ember-cli/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, here my solution:

app/components/select-rooms.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    name: null,
    quantityRooms: 1,
    rooms: '',
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.set('rooms', [1]);
    },
    actions: {
        changeQuantityRooms(value) {
            this.set('quantityRooms', value);
            this.set('rooms', []);

            for (var i = 0; i < this.get('quantityRooms'); i++) {
                this.get('rooms').pushObject(i);
            };
        },
        changeQuantityChildren(value) {
            this.set("quantity" + value.name, value.value);
            this.set(value.name, []);

            for (var i = 0; i < this.get("quantity" + value.name); i++) {
                this.get(value.name).pushObject(i);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

app/templates/components/select-rooms.hbs:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Quartos</label>

            <select name={{name}} onchange={{action "changeQuantityRooms" value="target.value"}} class="form-control">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {{#if rooms}}
            {{#each rooms as |room index|}}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                        <label>
                            Adultos <small>+18</small>
                        </label>

                        <select name={{concat name index "-adults"}} class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                        <label>
                            Crianças <small>até 17 anos</small>
                        </label>

                        <select name={{concat name index "-children"}} onchange={{action "changeQuantityChildren" value="target"}} class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        {{#if (get this (concat "quantity" name index "-children"))}}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <label>Idade das crianças: </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                {{#each (get this (concat name index "-children")) as | child i |}}
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">                                        
                                        <select name={{concat name index "-children-age-" i}} class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0">0</option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                            <option value="5">5</option>
                                            <option value="6">6</option>
                                            <option value="7">7</option>
                                            <option value="8">8</option>
                                            <option value="9">9</option>
                                            <option value="10">10</option>
                                            <option value="11">11</option>
                                            <option value="12">12</option>
                                            <option value="13">13</option>
                                            <option value="14">14</option>
                                            <option value="15">15</option>
                                            <option value="16">16</option>
                                            <option value="17">17</option>
                                        </select>                                    
                                    </div>
                                {{/each}}
                            </div>
                        {{/if}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</div>
```